# Dynamic Height for a 3 Section Layout

Tags: html, css

In a layout with a fixed height top navigation bar, a fixed width side-navigation bar where the rest of the space is for content, how can I make the side nav and content fill the remaining width even if the content in the content pane exceed the viewport's height.

[This pen](http://codepen.io/alanqthomas/pen/MJpwLP) will more accurately describe this situation. You can see that the content continues off of the `#content` div. How can I get it so that the side nav and content pane continue on for the rest of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is a little hacky solution but it works! If you're willing to use JS, I'll provide one without hacks:

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/Chris-Happy/pen/QdpjZP)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#container {
  background-color: green;
}

#topNav {
  height: 65px;
  background-color: red;
}

#sideNav {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
}

#content {
  background-color: blue;
  display:inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 200px)
}

div {
  text-align: center;
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="topNav">
     Top Nav
  </div>
  <div id="sideNav">
     Side Nav
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The sidebar's background is actually the container's background, making it look as it is.

This is how I would do it with JS:

```js
var sidebar = document.getElementById('sideNav');
var contentHeight = document.getElementById('content').offsetHeight + "px";

sidebar.style.height = contentHeight;

//Could you also write this in one line
//document.getElementById('sideNav').style.height = document.getElementById('content').offsetHeight + "px";
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#container {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#topNav {
  height: 65px;
  background-color: red;
}

#sideNav {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
}

#content {
  background-color: blue;
  display:inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 200px)
}

div {
  text-align: center;
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="topNav">
     Top Nav
  </div>
  <div id="sideNav">
     Side Nav
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, how would you do it with JS?

Comment: I would get the height of the content and make the height equal to it. It would be like five lines of code if you don't want to support responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an update of a very old method '[faux columns](http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns)' using a background gradient : `background:linear-gradient(to right, green 200px, blue 200px);` where green is paint from left on the first 200px(as sidebar) and then blue takes over:

```css
#container {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#topNav {
  height: 65px;
  background-color: red;
}

#sideNav {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 65px;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

#content {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 65px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 200px;
  right: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background:linear-gradient(to right, green 200px, blue 200px);
}

div {
  text-align: center;
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="topNav">
     Top Nav
  </div>
  <div id="sideNav">
     Side Nav
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```